# Enabling monitoring in azure cloud service

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles

I want to monitor a cloud service in azure portal . When I go to the azure portal , I get the message as "LEVELThis setting is not currently available." under monitoring tab.

Then I learnt from the msdn that , right click on web role in visual studio and check the "enable diagnostics" checkbox.

Then I redeployed the application azure portal .
Still the monitoring option is not configurable. What could be the issue ? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

For Storage you can enable monitoring and logging from within the respective tabs within the Storage configuration pages of the portal.

Jason